# No property searchSecurity found for type Security

Tags: java

There is an error using repository, custom repository, and repository impl.
i have no idea. i need you guys help. how can i do?

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="opn_api_security")
public class Security extends TraceModel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4182920514275414005L;

    @Id
    private String securityId;
    private String securityType;
    private String securityTitle;
    private String securityDescription;
    private String securityScheme;
    private String securityBearer;

    public String getSecurityId() {
        return securityId;
    }
    public void setSecurityId(String securityId) {
        this.securityId = securityId;
     ....
```

RestController

```
@ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(value = "/security")
    protected Page<Security> searchSecurity(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params, Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception
    {

      return securityService.searchSecurity(params, authentication, CommonUtils.PageRequest(params)) ;
    }
```

repository

```
@Repository
public interface SecurityRepository extends JpaRepository<Security, String>, SecurityRepositoryCustom {

}
```

custom repository

```
public interface SecurityRepositoryCustom {

    public Page<Security> searchSecurity(Map<String, String> params, PageRequest pageRequest, Authentication a) ;
}
```

repository impl

```
public class SecurityRepositoryimpl extends DefaultRepository implements SecurityRepositoryCustom{

    @Override
    public Page<Security> searchSecurity(Map<String, String> params, PageRequest pageRequest, Authentication a) {
        Map<String, Object> queryParms = new HashMap<>() ;
        List<String> where = new ArrayList<String>() ;
        List<String> orders = new ArrayList<>() ;

        ...

        return searchPage(Security.class, where, queryParms, orders, pageRequest) ;
    }
}
```

i didn't use Snake case 
so I don't know why that error came up.
i'm waiting for you guys answer! Thanks!

Comment: 'No property searchSecurity found for type Security!' The server doesn't go up due to an error.

Comment: oops!! i figure out!!! My bad. It didn't work because I named the file "impl"  .It worked fine when I changed it to "Impl".